# In gRPC, how to call the method of service without request?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, grpc, rpc, grpc-java

In java gRPC, can we call a function of a service from outside? Now, I have some clients and a server, they use the bidirectional streaming connection. Like this example, I want to call join() function when it meets a specific condition, instead of just calling it for a new request. Or do we have other methods to implement it? Thank you.

```
service.join(); // How can we call it?

private class serviceImpl extends serviceGrpc.serviceImplBase{
    public StreamObserver<> createConnection(){
        OnNext(){
            join();
        }
        OnError(){}
        ...
    }
    public void join(){}
}
```

Comment: What is the `join()` method? Is it a RPC service method or just an internal method on the server side? The server application is definitely free to call any local method. The problem is where is the entry point of the method call? If `join()` interacts with the StreamObserver used to talk to the remote peer, the call chain needs to be initiated by the remote/network. Otherwise, you do not even have a remote peer to talk to. Think about the client-server model, server cannot initiate communication without client first connects to it.

Comment: Thanks, voidzcy. I solved this problem. I passed this object outside the serviceImpl and then invoked methods of the service.